# How to "zoom-in" into your image with responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a image 3000x275 px that I want to show in full on 3000 wide screens (almost none) and zoom into the middle when screens get smaller. So a 320 screen gets to only see the middle 320 pixels of the banner.

I have tried many ways, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out to get this done. Note, I am using slick-slider to slide the images, so not sure if the solution is in this class or the css.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be achieved like so:

```css
header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 275px;
 background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/vimIKDj.png');
 background-size: 3000px 275px;
 background-position: center;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>Your header</header>
```

Comment: You are a hero. I did not know slick slider was also usable with background images, but it works perfectly!